# Example concearning the Schwartz Kernel Theorem?

Tags: distribution-theory

Let $\Omega_i\subseteq \mathbb R^{n_i}$ ($i=1, 2$) be open subsets. Given $K\in\mathscr{D}^\prime(\Omega_1\times \Omega_2)$ one can obtain a continuous linear operator $A:C^\infty(\Omega_2)\longrightarrow \mathscr{D}^\prime(\Omega_1)$ setting $$\langle A\phi, \psi\rangle:=\langle K, \psi\otimes \phi\rangle.$$ Conversely, for every continuous linear operator $A:C^\infty(\Omega_2)\longrightarrow \mathscr{D}^\prime(\Omega_1)$ there is unique $K\in\mathscr{D}^\prime(\Omega_1\times \Omega_2)$ such that: $$\langle A\phi, \psi\rangle=\langle K, \psi\otimes \phi\rangle.$$ This is called **Schwartz kernel theorem**.

I'm trying to understand the following example: Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and consider the continuous linear operator $A:C^\infty_0(\Omega)\longrightarrow \mathscr{D}^\prime(\Omega)$ given by $$\langle A\phi, \psi\rangle:=\int_{\Omega} \phi(x)\psi(x)\ dx.$$

Definying $K:C^\infty_0(\Omega\times \Omega)\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ by $$\langle K, \phi\rangle:=\int_{\Omega} \phi(x, x)\ dx,$$ we have $K\in\mathscr{D}^\prime(\Omega \times \Omega)$ and $$\langle K, \psi\otimes \phi\rangle=\int_{\Omega} (\psi\otimes \phi)(x, x)\ dx=\int_{\Omega} \psi(x)\phi(x)\ dx=\langle A\phi, \psi\rangle.$$ Hence $K$ is the kernel of $A$ of the Schwartz kernel theorem.  Up to this point everything is fine, but then my textbook writes: i.e., $$K(x, y)=\delta(x-y),$$ where $\delta$ is the diract distribution. This is confusing me, can anyone explain me?

Comment: It's fine to take it as the definition of $\delta(x-y)$, but if you want more background, if $p:\Omega\to\Omega'$ is a submersion and $f\in\mathscr D'(\Omega')$ then $p^*f\in\mathscr D(\Omega)$ is defined by $\langle p^*f,\phi\rangle=\langle f,\phi'\rangle$, where $\phi'$ is defined by $\phi'\,dx_1\dots dx_m=p_*(\phi\,dx_1\dots dx_n)$ ($p_*$ is the push-forward of differential forms or of measures, whichever you prefer). If $f$ is a function then $p^*f=f\circ p$.

In your case $p(x,y)=x-y$ and $f=\delta$.

Comment: Thanks @user8268 =) Could you recommend me a reference for this approach using pullbacks?

Comment: I found also the following: Given $\Omega, \Omega^\prime$ open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ and $u\in\mathscr{D}^\prime(\Omega)$ one might define $u(x-y)\in\mathscr{D}^\prime(\Omega\times \Omega^\prime)$ setting $\displaystyle \langle u(x-y), \phi(x, y)\rangle:=\int_{\Omega^\prime} \langle u(x), \phi(x+y, y)\ dy$.Has this anything to do with pullbacks?

Comment: reference: I like Duistermaat, Kolk: Distributions